# How can I implement Selectively focusing on an image?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

How can I implement Selectively focusing on an image? I'm trying to implement a bottom gradient layer for an image so that's why i've excluded topGradient filter.

Please see the link below. This is what I'm trying to achieve...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/selectively_focusing_on_an_image

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

    private func addBlur(for inputImage: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
            guard let h = inputImage.ciImage?.extent.size.height else { return nil }
    
            let bottomGradient = CIFilter.linearGradient()
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.35 * h), forKey:"inputPoint0")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIColor.green, forKey:"inputColor0")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.60 * h), forKey:"inputPoint1")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIColor.green, forKey:"inputColor1")
    
            let gradientMask = CIFilter.additionCompositing()
            gradientMask.setValue(bottomGradient.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
    
            let maskedVariableBlur = CIFilter.maskedVariableBlur()
            maskedVariableBlur.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            maskedVariableBlur.setValue(gradientMask.outputImage, forKey: "inputMask")
    
            let selectivelyFocusedCIImage = maskedVariableBlur.outputImage
    
            let ciContext = CIContext()
            let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(selectivelyFocusedCIImage!, from: selectivelyFocusedCIImage!.extent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
            return image
    }
```

Comment: The article you posted explains how to do it step by step. You posted some code but don't explain how it behaves. What part of the steps are you having trouble with? What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @DuncanC I'm trying to implement a bottom gradient layer for an image so that's why i've excluded topGradient filter. I've tried to debug it and can't figure it out where I'm doing wrong

Comment: What does your output look like, and how does that differ from your desired result? Please edit your original question to include that information (ideally including a screenshot of your source image and the output of your code.

Comment: additionCompositing needs two inputs - kCIInputBackgroundImageKey and kCIInputImageKey otherwise it will produce nothing (as in your code). It's used in the example you referenced  to combine two images. In your case you have just one image, so you don't need that filter at all.  Just set bottomGradient.outputImage to the "inputMask" input of the CIFilter.maskedVariableBlur directly.